# Any good books on web site architecture (not UI design)?

Tags: web-applications, architecture

I'm developing a web site that (like many other sites) use a bunch of different tools such as php, xml, xsl, json, jquery, css etc.

I'm looking for resources/books that can provide tips on how to use these tools more efficiently. Best practices, tips and tricks and that sort of stuff. For example how to structure files, when to use json instead of xml/xsl, ajax or no ajax and that kind of stuff. Luckily, I don't have to worry about UI design.

Does anyone know any good books/resources that deal with this?

Comment: add one more concern ... the software methodology you would follow should be at the end at least give you this benefit: IT IS EASY TO MAINTAIN. If it will be then make it more scalable and improving performance, and add more feature would not be difficult. The graph of maintaining should be below not crossing high to development times.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a beginner then consider to start from  [PHP MySQL Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166). And if you are intermediate then following are very good references concern on patterns, scalability, performance:

- [PHP-Architects-Guide-Design-Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0973589825)
- [AJAX and PHP: Building Responsive
  Applications](http://www.cristiandarie.ro/ajax-php/)
- [Building Scalable Web Sites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102356)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by looking into the MVC pattern of web development.
Once you have an overall pattern setup its easier to see where the other parts come into play.

Comment: won't it be good for him to see something that could help to design a web that will be easy to maintain and give good performance. I think this two should be on his higher nodes.